# How to remove multi sub-directories from URL with .htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an old website and I had changed my CMS site to WordPress.

Now I have many error 404 records in my Google Webmaster log.

I want to redirect an URL to a new structure...

---

Old URL:

```
www.mysite.com/fa/contents/detailXXXX/postslug
```

where `XXXX` is a 4-digit number, e.g. 4256

New URL:

```
www.mysite.com/postslug
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fa/contents/detail[0-9]{4}/postslug$ /postslug [R=301,L]
```

However if you need to know what digits were in the URL and use it in your script, use a cookie:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fa/contents/detail([0-9]{4})/postslug$ /postslug [CO=n:$1:.mysite.com:0:/,R,L]
```

...or use a query parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fa/contents/detail([0-9]{4})/postslug$ /postslug?n=$1 [QSA,R,L]
```